# Llamado Ajax con C# no funciona

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2015

Creé un proyecto en VisualStudio 2015, de plantilla... El problema es que no puedo hacer llamados desde jQuery Ajax. ¿A que se debe?

C#

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static Response<ProductosSP_obj> ObtenerProductosSP(Int32 FolioSp)
    {
        Response<ProductosSP_obj> response = new Response<ProductosSP_obj>();
        response = ObtenerDatosCotizacion_BLL.Instances.ObtenerProductosSP(FolioSp, _autenticacion.NombreUsuario);
        return response;
    }
```

JS

```
ObtenerProductosMarcas: function (idSp) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AdministrarSP.aspx/ObtenerProductosSP",
        data: "{FolioSp:" + JSON.stringify(idSp) + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d.RecordsCount > 0) {
                //* PROCESO PARA EL LLENADO DE LA TABLA INFORMATIVA

                //* SE LIMPIA LA TABLA PARA VOLVER A LLENARLA
                $('#ContenedorProductos').html('');

                //* SE RESETA EL PLUGING DE LA TABLA
                AdministrarSpecialPrice.ResetTable();

                $.each(response.d.ListRecords, function (indice, producto) {
                    $('#ContenedorProductos').append(
                            "<tr> " +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + producto.pc_cantidad + "</td>" +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + producto.prod_sku + "</td> " +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + producto.prod_noparte + "</td> " +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + producto.prod_desc + "</td> " +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + formatNumber.new(producto.pc_precio, '$', 2) + "</td>" +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + producto.tm_desc + "</td> " +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + formatNumber.new(producto.pc_subtotalps, '$', 2) + "</td> " +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + formatNumber.new(producto.pc_subtotaldl, '$', 2) + "</td> " +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + producto.sp_id + "</td>" +
                                " <td style='text-align:center'>" + producto.tsp_desc + "</td> " +
                           " </tr>");
                });

                //* SE FORMATEA LA TABLA
                AdministrarSpecialPrice.Table();

                //* PROCESO PARA EL LLENADO DE LA TABLA INFORMATIVA
            }
            else {
                notiLog(response.d.UserMessage);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alertaTimes("Error " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Si pones tu código sería más sencillo identificar la falla.

Comment: El código si lo se hacer, el problema es que como usé una plantilla, leí que no es posible los llamados Ajax, no se porqué.

Comment: ¿Cómo llamas al AJAX? ¿Qué devuelve "response" al poner un breakpoint en  return response;?

Comment: Yo se que es dificil entenderme Flixtr, el problema no es mi código, es la plantilla de Visual Studio.

Comment: Nunca entra, al poner un breakpoint, jamas llega, response no devuelve nada porque ni siquiera llega al CodeBehind

Comment: Si deseas depurar código JavaScript desde Visual Studio, te recomiendo utilizar como navegador Internet Explorer, con otros navegadores no es posible

Comment: @Flxtr todos los navegadores (a excepción de los movibles) tienen depurador de código JS.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver sí claro, todos los navegadores lo permiten, a lo que me refiero es "*depurar código JavaScript desde Visual Studio*", no directamente desde el navegador.

Comment: Si se como, pero te decía que el problema no es ese. Si quieres haz la prueba creando un nuevo proyecto e intentas hacer llamado ajax.
Archivo > Nuevo > Sitio Web... > Sitio de ASP.NET Web Form
Es una plantilla

Comment: response = Object {Message: "Error de autenticación.", StackTrace: null, ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: ¿Cómo llamas a esta variable _autenticacion.NombreUsuario ?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95525/ASP-NET-and-jQuery-to-the-Max

Comment: @fredyfx ¿A que te refieres con la pregunta?

Comment: tu response da un error de autenticación, por lo tanto me gustaría saber cómo llamas a la variable antes mencionada. Utiliza un breakpoint y revisa :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado el error con ayuda de un colega, resulta que es la configuracion dentro de la carpeta

> ***App_Code*** en el archivo ***RouteConfig.cs***

Lo que hay que hacer es cambiar el **AutoRedirectMode** en su propiedad que viene por default:

> ***RedirectMode.Permanent***    -->    ***RedirectMode.Off***

.CS

`public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        }
    }`

***A todos los que me apoyaron, gracias!***